# Array with duplicated keys

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to import some products from a CSV file. I'm using the example I found on the PHP site.

After getting some data and making some logic I ended up with this:

```
Array
(
    [attribute_set_id] => 9
    [status] => 1
    [visibility] => 4
    [store] => en
    [store] => es
)
```

As you can see, the key store is duplicated!

A var_dump

```
array(5) {
  ["attribute_set_id"]=>
  int(9)
  ["status"]=>
  int(1)
  ["visibility"]=>
  int(4)
  ["store"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["store"]=>
  string(2) "es"
}
```

To make things worse, `isset()` always returns `false` and `strlen` returns always `0`.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Edit:

After doing what fab suggested I ended up with this:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "attribute_set_id"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "store"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "sku"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "short_description"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "store"
}
```

The first store key has a length of 8?. How can I remove the hidden chars? Is there an option that is made at server level? Because this issue didn't happen before I move to another host company.

Comment: *"After getting some data and making some logic I ended up with this:"* Where's the code that does that? *" isset() always returns false and strlen returns always 0"* Where are the calls to `isset()` and `strlen()`?

Comment: Modify your logic so that 'store' itself is an array.

Comment: That shouldn't happen to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible if there are invisible characters in the key. To verify it, try this:

```
var_dump(array_keys($your_array));
```

and look for the string lengths.

Comment: Thanks @fab, it looks like you where right. Please check my edit and do you know the answer for my other question. Thanks again.

Comment: you should explain what your "making some logic" is. Do the keys come directly from CSV fields? Then the first thing to check would be if your CSV file is corrupt (i.e. with a hex editor)

Comment: yes, they come directly from CSV. (Sorry can't format code within this reply form)
`if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE)
     {
         $data = array_map('trim', $data);
          foreach ($data as $value)
          {
          } 
    }
}
`

Is there any any to clean up invisible chars?

Answer (score -5):

So you want to remove the duplicated keys?

Why not use the [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) method in PHP. So it'll look like this:

```
$arrayWithoutDuplicates = array_unique($originalArray);
```

Comment: `array_unique()` removes duplicated *values*. Duplicated keys should not be possible. It's either a bug in PHP or there're invisible characters in there.